# Inkscape CLI FileRevert doesn't work in 1.1 or 1.2, trying to refresh Inkscape GUI

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'm working on a tool for animating SVG that uses inkscape to manipulate SVG's, and I need to update inkscape to show the selected state of the animated SVG in order to let the user make changes (It is an external tool not a plugin).

For example: A rectangle goes from x: 100 to x:300, the user pauses the animation when rectangle is at x:200, then the tool saves the SVG state with x:200, the only problem is that inkscape is not refreshed, so I need to close and open inkscape, or manually go to File>Revert.

I'v been investigating and I found that there was a verb (before verbs were removed in 1.2) that is called FileRevert, I tried with version 1.1 and with inkscape GUI open this command:

```bash
inkscape --verb FileRevert test.svg
```

This is the full output with the command: (full log at the end)

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ ./ink2.AppImage --verb FileRevert test.svg

WARNING: ignoring verb FileRevert - GUI required for this verb.

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:6946): CRITICAL **: 08:40:38.988: static void Inkscape::FileVerb::perform(SPAction*, void*): assertion 'ensure_desktop_valid(action)' failed
```

So the error seems to be that is not detecting the GUI, idk if I have to tell to the cli where is the GUI or open inkscape from the GUI, but I tried this and the terminal is blocked until you close inkscape.

Then I tried with inkscape 1.2 actions since the documentation says that all verbs are available as actions:

[image]

but there is no FileRevert action in --action-list, and also there is no information about any deprecation of FileRevert on 1.2 release notes so It's been very difficult to make a guess on what is going on.

This is the output of trying FileRevert with actions: (full log at the end)

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ ./ink.AppImage --actions="FileRevert" test.svg

InkscapeApplication::parse_actions: could not find action for: FileRevert
```

So it seems it's not being able to find FileRevert action, probably that means that it's not supported or deprecated.

Im using linux mint in case that matters.

Any help is welcome, or any alternative solution to my problem... atm im considering so bad alternatives like just closing and reopening inkscape automatically every time you want to refresh it, or select inkscape window and trigger a hotkey to revert the file.

Thank you!

**Full log 1.1 Verb try:**

```
  user@user:~/Desktop$ ./ink2.AppImage --verb FileRevert test.svg
        Setting _INKSCAPE_GC=disable as a workaround for broken libgc
        Gtk-Message: 08:40:38.030: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
        
        ** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:6946): WARNING **: 08:40:38.964: <svg:rect id="">: CSS Style property: "stroke-width" with default value (1) not needed.
        
        ** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:6946): WARNING **: 08:40:38.964: <svg:rect id="rect786">: CSS Style property: "stroke-width" with default value (1) not needed.
        
        ** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:6946): WARNING **: 08:40:38.964: <svg:rect id="rect786">: CSS Style property: "stroke-width" with default value (1) not needed.
    
        WARNING: ignoring verb FileRevert - GUI required for this verb.
        
        ** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:6946): CRITICAL **: 08:40:38.988: static void Inkscape::FileVerb::perform(SPAction*, void*): assertion 'ensure_desktop_valid(action)' failed
```

**Full log 1.2 actions try:**

```
user@user:~/Desktop$ ./ink.AppImage --actions="FileRevert" test.svg
    Setting _INKSCAPE_GC=disable as a workaround for broken libgc
    Gtk-Message: 08:49:36.363: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
    InkscapeApplication::parse_actions: could not find action for: FileRevert
    
    ** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:7139): WARNING **: 08:49:37.377: <svg:rect id="">: CSS Style property: "stroke-width" with default value (1) not needed.
    
    ** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:7139): WARNING **: 08:49:37.377: <svg:rect id="rect786">: CSS Style property: "stroke-width" with default value (1) not needed.
    
    ** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:7139): WARNING **: 08:49:37.378: <svg:rect id="rect786">: CSS Style property: "stroke-width" with default value (1) not needed.
```

EDIT: Demo of the tool working and updating in Inkscape:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDAIVKd19YU

Comment: FileRevert is a verb. verbs are totally removed and replaced with actions in 1.2.x

Comment: @s.ouchene I know, that is why I tried with version 1.1 as a verb, and also as an action in 1.2 since it is supposed that all verbs where converted to actions:

https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.2#Behind_the_curtains

"Command line

    'verbs' have been removed. All verbs are available as 'actions'"

Comment: Verbs require the GUI. for 1.1.x use `--with-gui` option.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the Release notes. See the issue I opened here: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/7704

Comment: I tried ./inkscakpe --verb FileRevert --with-gui  test.svg, but it doesn't make sense, because it is going to open a new inkscape window, so how can you revert changes if you just opening a fresh project, the idea of revert file is to update the gui that is already open.

Comment: In the source code the comment says "// Need to create a document_revert that doesn't depend on windows." so maybe FileRevert only works for windows? in GUI work on linux, but maybe is just the command?

Comment: `winodws` doesn't refer to operating system but to GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the file_revert action is not implemented in 1.2.x and above versions for Inkscape. See the issue [here](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3881).

However, I would suggest using [dbus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) instead. Here is an example on how revert document using dbus when you have inkscape running:

```bash
gdbus call --session --dest org.inkscape.Inkscape --object-path /org/inkscape/Inkscape/window/1 --method org.gtk.Actions.Activate document-revert [] {}
```

To get the list of actions that you can invoke via dbus run the following command:

```bash
gdbus call --session --dest org.inkscape.Inkscape --object-path /org/inkscape/Inkscape/window/1 --method org.gtk.Actions.List
```

Instead of the terminal, you can also use dbus on your C++, Python, etc. codes. For the list of binding see: [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/).

- An example using C++: See here: https://github.com/makercrew/dbus-sample
- For Python, see: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbusExamples

Comment: Linux mint error maybe?
:~/Desktop$ gdbus call --session --dest org.inkscape.Inkscape --object-path /org/inkscape/Inkscape/window/1 --method org.gtk.Actions.Activate document-revert [] {}
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.inkscape.Inkscape was not provided by any .service files

Comment: You should have Inkscape open.

Comment: ok, I had 1.1 open, so I closed it and tryed with 1.2 and having this error now: Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused

Comment: ok I restarted my pc and now seems to have worked :)

Comment: @Of3lia: See the update. You can get the list of command that you can use via dbus.

Comment: Nice, the only thing missing now is that is going to open a popup to tell you that all changes will be lost, that's the expected behaviour anyways, but is annoying, It doesn't seem like there is an option to disable that :/

Comment: Actually is perfect! If I modify the file from a text editor it won't ask anything (and that is how I intend to make changes from my tool, by overwriting the file directly). Thanks :))

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDAIVKd19YU
Let me know what you think, Idk who should I email in inkscape to share this tool, I'v been checking on the page where they say all the alternatives to animate svg with inkscape and I haven't seen any solution so far, so I believe this could be interesting to share there maybe.

Comment: @Of3lia: Very interesting! You can reach out the developers in the dev channel of: chat.inkscape.org

Answer (score 1):

For Inkscape 1.1.x, using `dbus`:

```bash
gdbus call --session --dest org.inkscape --object-path /org/inkscape/desktop_0 --method org.inkscape.document.call_verb "FileRevert"
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here, if like me you just want to refersh inkscape UI from a script or an external program, on inkscape 1.3 there will be a "file-rebase" inkscape action that was made for this purpose, without need to use dbus, allowing us to use it on windows, linux and mac, and also we can target the current open window, thank Javier for all the work and the inkscape community. (you can do it directly from the terminal, with two terminals one to start the shell and the other to send commands to the current window) I got it working in an electron.js app like this:

First we store the child process:

```
this.inkscapeProcess = spawn(`${inkscapePath}`, ['-q', '--shell'])
```

--q is for telling it to target the current open inkscape window
--shell is for telling it to stay on shell mode so we can send actions that are going to be executed immediately (before it would take like a second or more because it had to wait to start the process every time )

And now we can send actions through stdin:

```
 this.inkscapeProcess.stdin.write(`selection-set-backup; file-rebase; selection-restore-backup; selection-empty-backup
    `)
```

(Note that the break line at the end of the string is needed to trigger the command, it kinda simulates an enter button)

This four actions not only refresh inkscape UI with filerebase, but also restore the selection (for example if you had selected 10 nodes of a path or a rect and a circle)

you can also trigger any other inkscape actions with that

This works as I said only with inkscape 1.3, at the moment haven't been released so you would need to go to gitlab repo and download master